# Wordpress - TwenteenSeventeen picture instead of a title

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm really new in coding, especially in css. I already read some tutorials but I like to change a specific thing. For my Website I use Wordpress. I also edited a few things in my CSS which already worked. Now I can't find a answer for how I can replace the title with a custom picture. 
Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGC4q.png) to watch a picture to understand what I mean.
Click [here](https://bo4community.de/) to acess my website.
I already tried some things, but it would be nice if someone can explain me how to do it.

Comment: My style.css https://codepen.io/H4nk5/pen/XyoLdo

Comment: I don't understand -- the picture and your current website seem identical. What do you want changed?

Comment: I like to Put a picture in the header instead of this text!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit `header.php` in the twenty seventeen to display only a picture.

This source code is on your wordpress server in `wp-content/themes/twenty-seventeen/header.php`: https://github.com/WordPress/twentyseventeen/blob/master/header.php

You'll want to replace line 31:

`<?php get_template_part( 'components/header/header', 'image' ); ?>`

With something like

`<img src="banner.png" />`

You'll have to adjust the location of `banner.png` to where you actually upload the image.

After you've got that working and it's basically what you want, you can wrap the image tag in a `a` tag so the banner links back to your home page, if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you for this derailed and helpful answer!